# how can i make particles chase a specified target with geometry nodes simulations?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

[image]

Also how can i integrate it with my current system?

Here is the uploaded blend file for inspecting if needed

https://we.tl/t-jAgUoEFBiI

Comment: The particle chasing part may or may not be difficult depending on your needs. A simple setup can easily made with a bunch of vector math nodes only! If you have a reference, plz provide it. As for the integration part, it depends competely on the nodes you have. Since you have provided a pic of your overall system and not the individual node groups as well, there isn't much help that can be provided for the integration aspect. But again, if the groups are complex ones, then there is even less chance that you will recieve help regarding it.

Comment: you're right i apologize. i have uploaded the blend file for users to inspect more closely

Comment: Any chance you could reupload the .blend file? I'm curious to see your original node setup.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you wanna try with this as a starting point?

i just "misuse" your acceleration to move the particles.

[image]

result:

scale = 3

[image]

scale = 5

[image]